# Disable an parent link for dropdown menu but keep css

Tags: theming, javascript

i have this menu : http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/1000/

And I disabled the href link "bewerken" with

```
a[href="/test4/disabled"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

But now my css does not show on that link, does anyone have any idea on how I can keep my css on that link but still have it disabled ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
  e.preventDefault();
```

under

```
 $('.topmenu').click(function(e){
```

will disable link redirection.